# Are Java Extensions till working on Play Framework?

Tags: java, templates, playframework, version

I am using Play Framework 2.1.2 and when I use some Java Extensions like:

```
@clock.getDate.format("dd MMMM yy")
```

They work, but in the Play Framework documentation they are not mentioned since 1.* versions(http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.2/javaextensions).

Do you know if they are still being supported? They are really usefull and they are working now, but I'm afraid because my application could die in a not too distant future.

Answer (score 2):

Java Extension known from Play 1.x doesn't exists in Play 2 anymore.

As currently templates are just Scala functions, you can create custom Java class containing such things like time formatters and call it directly from the view.

Comment: But the annoying thing is that is still working, even not being referenced in ScalaTemplates(http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.2/ScalaTemplates)